# How do I get milliseconds in a QDateTime with QSqlQuery in Qt C++?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT LOG_TIME FROM PCY_LOG_EVENTS;
```

This returns data in the format "DD-MMM-YY HH.MM.SS.MS" like this:

```
30-OCT-11 09.00.57.638000000 AM
```

In my Qt code, I have this:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT LOG_TIME from PCY_LOG_EVENTS", db);

while(query.next()) {
    //Displays a QMessageBox with the millisecond part of the QDateTime
    this->messageBox(QString::number(query.value(0).toDateTime().time().msec()));
}
```

I get 0 for all the millisecond values. Is there a reason why the millisecond values are not being stored? How would I get the millisecond values?

Comment: Have you tried getting the value as a QString (`value(0).toString()`)? What does that return?

Comment: It returns something like this: "2011-11-21T12:25:56"

Comment: I fear you'll have to implement a workaround then (convert to a string format in the query, do a manual QString -> QDateTime conversion in Qt with a custom format), but I don't know for sure...

Comment: That's what I did originally, but there is no millisecond in the QString either though.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think you'll need to make the data type your query (SQL) returns a string-type and not a date-type.

Answer (score 2):

Get the query value as a `QString`

```
QString dateTimeString = query.value(0).toString();
```

Then use the static `fromString` function of the `QDateTime`. You have to specify the format of your string. I assume the days of the month have a leading zero

```
QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(dateTimeString, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.zzz000000 A")
```

Notice the milliseconds part :`zzz000000`. Since the max value can be 999 the trailing zeros of your example make no sense. So by using the `zzz` followed by the zeros you can get the miliseconds stored in your string. The only possible problem is that your month part uses upper case letters while the `MMM` returns the month abbreviation with just the first letter capitalized. I hope there won't be a problem with it.

Once you do the conversion you can easily get the milliseconds:

```
int ms = dateTime.time().msec();
```

For more formatting options [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatetime.html#fromString-4)

Comment: I just tried this and this didn't work. Like I said above, query.value(0).toString() gives you something like this: "2011-11-21T12:25:56"

Comment: Try to change your query to : "SELECT CONVERT(LOG_TIME, CHAR(31)) from PCY_LOG_EVENTS"

Comment: I get this error when I try that: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 25

Comment: Did you have a work around of this? I guess I have the same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582537/mysql-timestamp-to-qdatetime-with-miliseconds

Comment: @KcFnMi Sorry, this was years ago and I don't remember what I did to work around it. I saw that in your question you were able to find a solution though!