# MySQL TIMESTAMP to QDateTime with milliseconds

Tags: mysql, qt

If I use a QSqlTableModel to access a MySQL database I can convert a TIMESTAMP field using the following:

```
QDateTime dateTime = index(section, column).data().toDateTime();
QString str = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz");
```

So `str` shows, i.e. `2014-06-22 22:11:44.221`.
But I want to access the database using QSqlQuerry, so I do:

```
QDateTime dateTime = query.value(column).toDateTime();
str = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz");
```

But now I'm missing the milliseconds, `str` shows `2014-06-22 22:11:44.000`. What's the proper way to see the milliseconds?

If I do `str = query.value(column).toString();` then I get `2014-06-22T22:11:44`.

Comment: Are you sure that TIMESTAMP has nanoseconds?

Comment: Sure. Besides seeing the miliseconds while accessing with QTableModel, I can confirm it accessing the database with HeidiSQL (www.heidisql.com).

Comment: HeidiSQL actually says the field is a TIMESTAMP(3).

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql), probably it will help you

Comment: Unfortunately I did not understand (It appers to me that question is more about MySQL, nothing about Qt). I've edited the question. Is there any chance that the query above cannot retrieve the miliseconds?

Comment: Looks like the issue here is the same as (without response) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229658/how-do-i-get-milliseconds-in-a-qdatetime-with-qsqlquery-in-qt-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this page:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional
>   seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. In
>   particular, as of MySQL 5.6.4, any fractional part in a value inserted
>   into a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column **is stored** rather than discarded.

So, the millisecond is there in MySQL! But the `query.value()` does not get it - at this point in the Qt history as pointed by [@peppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873944/peppe) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625048/store-qdatetime-with-millisends-in-mysql).

Relating back to the original question: There is no proper way to see the millisecond since the query does not have it. One alternative could be to modify the query, from:

```
SELECT timestamp FROM table;
```

to

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s.%f') as timestamp FROM table;
```

And then finish the job with:

```
QString str = query.value(column).toString();
QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(str, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz000");
```

I got the insight from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229658/how-do-i-get-milliseconds-in-a-qdatetime-with-qsqlquery-in-qt-c).

Answer (score 2):

From [MySQL 5.1 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html):

> A `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. Although this fractional part is recognized, it is discarded from values stored into `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` columns.

It seems like seconds is the best you can do with timestamp.

Comment: I checked the script which creates the database, the field is a TIMESTAMP(3) - MySQL 5.6.17. Definitely it has miliseconds. Do you agree? Also, I've checked how the INSERT is made, it's a QDateTime::toString with the same format as said in the question. At this point I'm in doubt if this approach is correct (the best), I mean: Is TIMESTAMP(3) the best type to store a QDateTime::toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz")? Anyway now I think I put the question to much in the MySQL side, my intent is to work in the Qt side (how to make the miliseconds appear in that query above?).