# Store QDateTime (with millisends) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, qt

I've seen issues ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229658/how-do-i-get-milliseconds-in-a-qdatetime-with-qsqlquery-in-qt-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582537/mysql-timestamp-to-qdatetime-with-miliseconds)) related to retrieving the milliseconds part of a `QDateTime` after inserting in MySQL database.

What's the proper way to do that(should I do `QDateTime::toString` and store it in a `TIMESTAMP(3)` field)?

Comment: I don't think you can just use QDateTime (as of Qt 5.5). Milliseconds support in MySQL is relatively a new feature and nobody has added the code necessary to read them back... see http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.cpp#n142

Comment: I've made a reference to your comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582537/mysql-timestamp-to-qdatetime-with-milliseconds/31631751#31631751).